MLflow conflicting documentation on make_metric
I am trying to implement a custom metric to be included in the MLflow evaluate function and the official documentation conflicts with examples on the Github repository and my own empirical experiments. I was wondering if someone could help me on the "correct" way to implement a custom metric and/or why my own implementation differs from the official resources.
For context, I am currently using MLflow version 2.9. The first conflict is between the official documentation and the Github examples. The make_metric function requires a eval_fn argument, the function that actually implements the metric. In the official documentation, the eval_fn argument has the following signature:
def eval_fn(
    predictions: pandas.Series,
    targets: pandas.Series,
    metrics: Dict[str, MetricValue],
    **kwargs,
) -> Union[float, MetricValue]:

However, in the Github example (and in this Udemy course), an eval_fn is defined as:
def squared_diff_plus_one(eval_df, _builtin_metrics):
    """
    This example custom metric function creates a metric based on the ``prediction`` and
    ``target`` columns in ``eval_df`.
    """
    return np.sum(np.abs(eval_df["prediction"] - eval_df["target"] + 1) ** 2)

I tried implementing a custom metric following this example as follows:
def logloss_wrapper(eval_df, _builtin_metrics, **kwargs):
    negative_examples = eval_df["negative_examples"]
    positive_examples = eval_df["positive_examples"]
    predictions = eval_df["predictions"]
    return (-(positive_examples * np.log(predictions) + negative_examples * np.log(1-predictions))).sum()/(positive_examples+negative_examples)

This didn't work with the following error message:
MlflowException: Error: Metric calculation failed for the following metrics:
Metric 'logloss_wrapper' requires the columns ['eval_df', '_builtin_metrics', 'kwargs']

Below are the existing column names for the input/output data:
Input Columns: (list of input columns)
Output Columns: ['predictions']
To resolve this issue, you may want to map the missing column to an existing column
using the following configuration:
evaluator_config={'col_mapping': {<missing column name>: <existing column name>}}

Passing the positive and negative examples as kwargs also didn't work. But the following solution worked:
def logloss_wrapper(positive_examples, negative_examples, predictions):
    return (-(positive_examples * np.log(predictions) + negative_examples * np.log(1-predictions))).sum()/(positive_examples+negative_examples)

And I don't see how this fits with the definitions above.
